# inclusive exclusion in regular expression

Tags: regex

Trying to create an inclusive exclusion in regular expression using the following syntax.  Not having much succcess so figured try my luck with stackoverflow.

EG of URL I'm trying run exclusion on is:

```
'https://somesite.domain.com:port/folder1/subfolder1/subfolder2/18`
```

Regex I've for it is:

```
\d{2,3}\/folder1\/subfolder1\/subfolder2(?!18)\d
```

The above regex cover all from 181-189.  I only want to see 18.

Comment: is it because you have a final \d on the end?  this will force it to be 18 with a third digit afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the *end of the string* anchor:

```
\d{2,3}\/folder1\/subfolder1\/subfolder2\/(?!18$)\d
```

or a slash or another character if your string is only a substring (not at the end):

```
\d{2,3}\/folder1\/subfolder1\/subfolder2\/(?!18\/)\d
```